# Access to webapp with flask on host='0.0.0.0' port 5000 from other devices in vpn network

Tags: flask

I have VM on Azure which I connect to through VPN from other devices.
I have there postgres server which I host on port 5432 and I use this database from other devices in same VPN.
I set there also flask webapp on host='0.0.0.0' port 5000 (development server) and I can't connect to this through other devices in same VPN. Why?

My goal is create flask webapp on VM and host it only for devices connected to my VPN, not public.
Is it possible? What I did wrong?
What is the diffrence between postgres host and flask host?

Comment: check your firewall and azure virtual network settings to see if that port is open for traffic within your vlan

Comment: I had so many problems with that when I set port 5432 for postgres. I will check it again. Thank you.